# Spring-boot restful web service connect to ftp server

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot, ftp

Firstly , I am really new to spring framework and java.

I have the following, FTP server with subdirectory containing files.

I want to make getAll / getOne request to the server and also a process method where I will do asynchronous processing of a file and save it to a new subdirectory and notify client once processing complete.

So far I have managed to make GET / POST / DELETE requests to hard coded entities and display this in browser, also got similar functionality using embedded derby server.
Have model with constructor, getters and setters, created mappings to URI in my controller which calls my services to complete the request.

I'm struggling to figure out where do I implement the code to actually connect to the ftp server and how i do the processing asynchronously on the server itself.

Any link to resources or pseudo code to help me understand would be amazing, spring docs are quite complicated for my level. I couldn't find any simple(ish) examples to help me understand.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a FtpService class and annotate it with @Service. create a connect method inside it.

in the main method use the ftp service to connect to the ftp

```
FtpService ftpService = context.getBean(FtpService.class);
ftpService.connect();
```

you can read about the @Async annotation that can make the process of the recieved files work asynchronously

Comment: Will my get methods first call the ftpService to connect to server then run the code to get whatever im looking for and populate my model with it.

Comment: No,
you will call the ftpService.connect in the main method of the spring application, then you will be connected to the ftpServer. After that the server which will handle your requests will continue to start up.
So all in all you need to connect to the ftpServer just one time at the very beginning

Comment: are you using spring-boot ?

Comment: Yes I am using spring boot, currently my getAll is really simple,

Comment: return statement with list of objects. So my new service gonna need to add some code there to navigate to a directory on server then for each file create new object and add it to the list